# Cannot bind ports to my container in Google Container optimized VM

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a docker container on Google Container-optimized VM in GCE.

Here is my dockerfile. I built a container image and push it to gcr.io.

```
FROM nginx:1.9
COPY config /etc/nginx
```

And I wrote a container manifest file.

```
version: v1beta2
containers:
  - name: test
    image: gcr.io/myproject/test
    ports:
      - name: http
        hostPort: 80
        containerPort: 80
      - name: https
        hostPort: 443
        containerPort: 443
```

I deployed to GCE with the manifest file, but port binding was not as I had expected. Why did the host port 80 and 443 redirect to google_containers/pause instead of myproject/test?

```
local$ gcloud compute instance create test \
  --image container-vm \
  --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=container.yaml \
  --zone us-central1-b \
  --machine-type f1-micro \
  --tags http-server,https-server

local$ gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-b test

test$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE                                COMMAND              CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                    NAMES
818828ccc2c6 gcr.io/myproject/test:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon of 23 seconds ago Up 22 seconds                                          k8s_test.9de3822_7f9f8ecace94a22b2bea59ee14f3bcd0-test_df40d10c4dfa4
f40d10c4dfa4 gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0 "/pause"             32 seconds ago Up 31 seconds 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp k8s_POD.c6ce2a78_7f9f8ecace94a22b2bea59ee14f3bcd0-test_default_7f9f8ecace94a22b2bea59ee14f3bcd0-test_64d51838
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had updated version of the manifest v1beta2 to v1 (v1beta3) and tried it again. The result of port binding seems to be same as previous one, but the container can communicate with external network through port 80 and 443.

```
version:1
kind: Pod
spec:
    restartPolicy: Always
    dnsPolicy: Default
    containers:
        - name: test
          image: gcr.io/myproject/test
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
              - name: http
                hostPort: 80
                containerPort: 80
                protocol: TCP
              - name: https
                hostPort: 443
                containerPort: 443
                protocol: TCP
```